# Azure. The system memory and CPU change cause slowdown app respond?

Tags: azure, performance, slowdown

we had a problem at 24th of February between 12:35 and 12:50 (pm by utc). Our app starts to respond slowly and it led to failures, but our app didn’t overload [Availability and Performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cH0p.png).
Could the system memory and CPU change cause slowdown our app respond? If yes, then how can avoid this problem next time?
There is a screenshot of our app slowdown chart: [Web App Slow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mInkM.png)
In this time we detect change in physical memory and CPU [Memory Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaDNk.png), [High CPU Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPr4x.png)

Availability and Performance tools detected top 5 slow request execution. It is requests from our app service to external services. Could these requests the overall performance of the app service or app service plan?

Comment: `the system memory and CPU change` what change? Besides, it's impossible to say what's going on from a couple of graphs, knowing *nothing* about your application and environment. SO is a Q&A site about *programming* questions, not server management much less third-party support. Have you tried contacting Azure support?

Comment: BTW those graphs show that the load moved from one machine to the other, not any kind of CPU change. The CPU and RAM consumption remained the same but on a different machine. It looks like traffic switched from one machine to the other. Was there a failover? A deployment? A manual redirection?

Comment: The development team did not perform any manipulations at the time. The switch was made automatically and there is no additional information about it.

Comment: So what do you expect by posting a question at Stack Overflow? This isn't Azure support, or even a Microsoft site. You don't have a programming question. Even if you posted a question at eg serverfault.com, nobody would be able to tell you what happened with your Azure services.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Low compute resource can lead to slow performance (application using high memory/CPU).

Other reasons for performance issue at application level issues, network requests taking a long time, application code or database queries being inefficient, or application crashing due to an exception. To isolate and avoid such issues in future you may try these steps.

Firstly, review the service heath for any reported issues during that time-frame:
You can track the health of the service on the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/)

From the screenshots you have shared, it looks like there **2 5xx** errors and **48 4xx** errors, you may review the logs to fetch more details on the issue.

-Access Kudu - https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/.

- To analyze logs and collect diagnostic dumps as required.

[Enable diagnostics logging for apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs)

Typically, in Azure App Service, for increased performance and throughput, you can adjust the scale at which you are running your application. I'm unsure on what App Service Plan (ASP) you're using.
If you have multiple Apps under a single ASP, the compute resources are shared by all of those running apps. Based on your requirement and usage you may either consider changing your App Service plan to a higher pricing tier or scale-out instances.